# PDF file error Cannot access a closed Stream

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, mvcrazortopdf

I would like to generate a PDF file for my reporting module. Here is my code in the controller in generating the PDF file.

```
public ActionResult Reports_CARF(int carf_id= 0) 
{
    var data = db.Dept_Approval_Data_vw.Where(x => x.carf_id == carf_id && x.request_category == "PETC Local Applications" && x.verified_by != null).ToList();

    return new PdfActionResult(data);
}
```

I have include this following in my controller:

```
using MvcRazorToPdf;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

Now, when I try to run this code, I got this error displayed in the browser.
[image]

Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your use of `using` structures and explicit `close` calls most likely is wrong as the exception is an `ObjectDisposedException`, most probably in your `PdfActionResult` implementation.

Comment: Any solution to this issue? I am also struggling with same?

Comment: PDFHelpers\MvcRazorToPdf.cs:47  Reason for error  Causing this error and cod is on this pastebin  http://pastebin.com/JqJ4hfpW  @mki  can any one help ??

Answer (score 0):

Based on personal experience, this is likely to be badly formed XHTML coming from your view causing an unhandled exception in MvcRazorToPdf.

Try rendering the view, e.g. return `View()` instead of `return new PdfActionResult(data)`, and running the output through an XHTML validator.